# Binding Syncfusion SfAutoComplete's AutoCompleteSourceProperty source to List of strings

Tags: c#, mvvm, autocomplete, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am trying to use Synfusion's **SfAutoComplete** control and bind it's **AutoCompleteSourceProperty** property to a List (or ObservableCollection).

I am using MVVM, and I have other Bindings between this View and my ViewModel which work fine.

Here's part of my **View** code:

```
var searchAuto = new SfAutoComplete
{
    Watermark = "Enter search terms"
};
searchAuto.SetBinding(SfAutoComplete.AutoCompleteSourceProperty, "MeshListAuto");
searchAuto.SuggestionMode = SuggestionMode.Contains;
searchAuto.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
searchAuto.MaximumDropDownHeight = 200;
```

And here's part of my **ViewModel** code:

```
List<string> _meshListAuto;
public List<string> MeshListAuto
{
    get { return _meshListAuto; }
    set
    {
        _meshListAuto = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

(I have tried the above as an **ObservableCollection** as well...)

```
foreach (var termSet in test.TranslationStack.TermSet)
{
    if (termSet.Field == "MeSH Terms")
    {
        MeshListAuto.Add(termSet.Term);
        Debug.WriteLine(MeshListAuto.Count);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **OnPropertyChanged** event on the List doesn't seem to fire when I add to the List from anywhere outside the ViewModel's constructor.

So if I put this line **in the constructor**:

```
MeshListAuto.Add("test item");
```

then "test item" is the only thing that appears in the SfAutoComplete list, but nothing else.

I have checked and the strings *are* getting added to my bound List, but only the elements that are added in the constructor show up.

**As a temporary solution**

I used the messaging service to notify my SfAutoComplete control that the List it's supposed to be bound to has changed:

In the ViewModel:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<List<string>>(MeshListAuto, "list_updated");
```

In the View:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<List<string>>(this, "list_updated", (sender) =>
{
    searchAuto.AutoCompleteSource = sender;
});
```

But I guess this is not very compatible with MVVM practices, right?

Comment: @l-zan, it seems to be a problem about how the items are refreshed and if this control supports it, Anyway you need a observablecollection.

Comment: @JesusAngulo, yep you are right, but it seems like this control doesn't like ObservableCollections...

Answer (score 0):

We have considered the requirement  as feature and it will be available in our upcoming Volume 3 SP1 which is scheduled to be rolled out in the month of October 2016.

Comment: is it implemented in new release?